# How to put bottom sheet ui of jetpack compose on the top of custom bottom navigation bar and it should be draggable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

Hello I am using material 3 bottom sheet in jetpack compose (I cannot show whole code or images due to security issues)

Here is a partial code of bottom navhost

```
  val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            Column() {

                NavigationBarComponent(navController = navController)

            }

        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Background {
            EVBackground {
```

Now I call the bottom sheet from above the scaffold.

```
 BottomSheetUi()

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            Column() {

                NavigationBarComponent(navController = navController)

            }
```

My issue is that the bottom sheet is stuck to the very bottom of the screen and the navhost navbar gets hidden by it. I want the bottom sheet to start above it and collapse with drag handle. So the offset should be just above the bottom nav bar.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is possible to put bottom sheet above `bottomBar`, but `bottomBar` composables would not be clickable and when collapsed bottom sheet would briefly cover `bottomBar` content, not go behind it. Is it something you need?

Comment: No obviously I would need the bottombar  items to be clickable @JanItor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have managed to achieve it using `Scaffold` with a nested `BottomSheetScaffold`.

[image]

```
    val scaffoldSheetState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {...},
    ) { innerPadding ->
        // 40.dp for the drag handle
        val bottomPadding = innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding() + 40.dp
        BottomSheetScaffold(
            scaffoldState = scaffoldSheetState,
            sheetPeekHeight = bottomPadding,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
            sheetContent = {
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .padding(bottom = bottomPadding)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Text("Sheet content")
                    Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
                    Button(onClick = {
                        scope.launch { scaffoldSheetState.bottomSheetState.partialExpand() }
                    }) {
                        Text("Hide bottom sheet")
                    }
                    Button(onClick = { }) {
                        Text("Some button")
                    }
                }
            },
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(it)
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {
                Text(text = "Main content")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yes with Scaffold even I waa able to do it later on, but anyways I will mark this answer. But one more issue that I am facing is setting the background of the bottom sheet background with image , and give a sheetDragHandle , is it possible to do both at the same time ?

Comment: @Pritish I think yes, what kind of problems do you have? I think adding a `Box` with an `Image` inside should work for the background. If you want the handle to be a part of the background, set `sheetDragHandle = {}`.

Comment: I didn't even know this class existed.  Thanks!